# Full width of cgroup in "ps -w -w -e -o pid -o cgroup -o cmd"?

Tags: ps

```
ps -w -w -e -o pid -o cgroup -o cmd
```

shows `cmd` in full width, but `cgroup` is truncated:

```
...
6598 11:devices:/user.slice,6:pi /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
...
```

Why is that?

I know that without `-w -w`, `cmd` is also truncated.

I know that I could do `ps -w -w -e -o pid -o cgroup:1024 -o cmd` and that *probably* no cgroup information is longer than 1024 chars. Probably, not reliably. There is no good number here.

I know that I could do `ps -w -w -e -o pid -o cgroup` omitting the `cmd`field. Then `cgroup` is long. If I swap `cmd` and `cgroup` then `cmd` gets truncated.

But can't I get `ps` to print both `cgroup` and `cmd` in "full width" what ever that happens to be?

(And why doesn't `ps` just have a `--json` output parameter? Oh, well...)